# Appropriate SQL type for variable length url's and descriptions?

Tags: sql, varchar

I have a small db app that stores URL's of all lengths, some extremely long (hundreds of characters) and some of typical length (< 50 characters). Am I introducing inefficiencies into the DB by declaring VARCHAR(1000) (or higher) as the type? Is there something better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

As for me - I'm sure 1000 chars is quite enough for any url

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your RDMBS.  In PostGreSQL you use type `TEXT` for variable length strings.